# Trying to get and print data from google search editbox but got InvalidElementStateException

Tags: java, selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a word in google search editbox and capture all the related list item and display it. But while doing so i got Got a exception
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions. I went through the same exception related question and according to them changed my code but none of them help.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

public class AutoIt {
 public static void main(String[] args){
  WebDriver window;
  FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
  profile.setEnableNativeEvents(false);
  window = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
try{
window.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
window.manage().window().maximize();
window.findElement(By.id("gs_htif0")).sendKeys("Shantanu Nandan");
window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
List<WebElement> list=window.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@style='width: 100%;']/span"));
window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
for(WebElement data:list){
    System.out.println(data.getAttribute("value"));
 }//for
}//try
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("Got a exception");
    e.printStackTrace();
    window.close();
}//catch
finally{
    System.out.println("Finally Block Executed ....");
    window.close();
    window.quit();
}//finally
  }//main
}//class
```

Exception which i got for this code

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions
Command duration or timeout: 47 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'omega-d52b83806', ip: '10.0.0.4', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch:     'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: d29ef567-95a8-47ce-bf84-c510cbb2756d
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true,     cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true,   browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=29.0.1}]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
at      org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:89)
at AutoIt.main(AutoIt.java:21)
  Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions
  Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
  System info: host: 'omega-d52b83806', ip: '10.0.0.4', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.preconditions.enabled(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous7567378475668954944webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:8185)
at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous7567378475668954944webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10814)
at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous7567378475668954944webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10831)
at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous7567378475668954944webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10836)
at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous7567378475668954944webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10778)
Finally Block Executed ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have selected the wrong element.

Use the below one for search text box

```
wb=window.findElement(By.name("q"));
```

Use the below for getting output suggestions.

```
List<WebElement> list = window.findElements(By.className("gsq_a"));
```

To get the values from the list, use getText() method instead of getAttribute().

```
for (WebElement data : list) {
System.out.println(data.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

public class AutoSuggest {

```
WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void seup()
{
    driver= new FirefoxDriver();

}
@Test
public void test_autosuggest()
{
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gs_lc0']//input[@id='gbqfq']")).sendKeys("h");

    WebElement wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='gssb_e']"));
    List<WebElement> links= wb.findElements(By.tagName("div"));

    System.out.println("the total "+links.size());

    for (int i=0;i<links.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
    }


}
```

}